# Verify the password in AIX

Tags: unix, cryptography, passwords, aix

Is there a way in AIX to verify given password is correct or not using C or shell command?

I want to validate if the given password is correct or not, without using "su" command. I want to use C function or some system command to executed within C code.

Since AIX is not supporting shadow.h, I cannot use `getspnam()` function

Comment: How about function `authenticate(3)` from `usersec.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment @Lorinczy below is the C code to validate pasword of a user

```
#include <usersec.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *authmsg;
    int authsuccess;
    int reenter = 0;
    authsuccess = (authenticate(argv[1],argv[2],&reenter,&authmsg) == 0);
    printf("Result: %d \n", authsuccess);
    return(authsuccess);
}
```

Pass username and password as parameter. Returns 0 if successful and nonzero if authentication failed